# c# TCP socket server not responding to client

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, mono

I have a C# server running under Ubuntu 12.04 using Mono, with the following code :

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Socket ready...");
    using (Socket handlerSocket = listenerSocket.Accept())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New request...");
        BackgroundWorker newBackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        Console.WriteLine("Buffer allocated...");
        handlerSocket.Receive(buffer);
        //newBackgroundWorker.DoWork += (s, o) =>
        //{
        using (Socket Sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Buffer received...");
            string request = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer);
            Console.WriteLine("New request from : {0} /t Request : {1}", ((IPEndPoint)handlerSocket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString(), request);
            if (request.Contains("$GetBattleList"))
            {
               //Chain of if's and else's continues
               //The following else if is the only case being tested

            else if (request.Contains("$GetZeroBasedProfile"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sending profile...");
                Sender.Connect(handlerSocket.RemoteEndPoint); //Fails here due to not being able to reach the client application, throws a timeout exception
                Sender.SendFile(_profileLocation);
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Invalid request. Ignoring...");
        }
    }
}
```

The server is able to receive the client requests, but is however unable to respond because it fails to connect everytime.
Am I missing something in my code or is there something else at work here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you accept a connection using a server socket, what you get is a socket connected to the client. You don't have to create a new socket to connect (in fact, you can't). So, instead of creating and using `Sender`, just use `handlerSocket`:

```
handlerSocket.SendFile(_profileLocation);
```

Answer (score 3):

The additional Socket `Sender` you're declaring is unnecessary. The `handlerSocket` you receive from `listenerSocket.Accept()` is already the socket you can use to communicate with the client.